# M1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code / encounted error while building this device

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, android-studio, apple-m1

Good afternoon everyone,

Ive been trying to make the app run and it doesnt work i’ve tried everything please help.

Thank you so much in advance!

MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
macOS Monterey version 12.3.1
Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)
android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3
flutter channel stable
everything running in rosseta 2 including the simulator

Command Flutter build iOS:

Android studio:

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[13420]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e1eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1043644f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[13420]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e1f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104364548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[13420]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e1f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104364598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[13420]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e1fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1043645e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[13420]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e1ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104364638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[13420]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1e56e2040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104364688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2022-04-26 12:51:00.034 xcodebuild[13420:385696] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-04-26 12:51:00.035 xcodebuild[13420:385696] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/75/1k4jl9xd4qn5p8fstmtzs43h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Ajgo6z/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirfVfbjn/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
          (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
    int best_offset;
                   ^
                    = 0
1 warning generated.
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
          (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
    int best_offset;
                   ^
                    = 0
1 warning generated.
4 warnings generated.
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
          (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
    int best_offset;
                   ^
                    = 0
1 warning generated.
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:40:22: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:40:22: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 ?? <#default value#>
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:40:22: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                !
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:40:22: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 as Any
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:41:18: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:41:27: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                   ?? <#default value#>
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:41:27: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                  !
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:41:27: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                   as Any
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:67:21: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:67:21: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                               ?? <#default value#>
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:67:21: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                              !
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:67:21: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                               as Any
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:68:20: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:68:20: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
                             ?? <#default value#>
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:68:20: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
                            !
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:68:20: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
                             as Any
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:69:21: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "middleName": middleName,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.6/ios/Classes/PaymentExtensions.swift:69:21: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "middleName": middleName,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                               ?? <#default value#>
/Users/aryuna/
lib/Screens/me/Selling/selling.dart:436:70: Error: The getter 'TEST' isn't defined for the class 'Screen'.
 - 'Screen' is from 'package:uniyo/class/Util.dart' ('lib/class/Util.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'TEST'.
                            utils.changeScreen(context, utils.screen.TEST);
                                                                     ^^^^
lib/class/Basket.dart:175:33: Error: The getter 'bookingTime' isn't defined for the class 'BasketItem'.
 - 'BasketItem' is from 'package:uniyo/class/BasketItem.dart' ('lib/class/BasketItem.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bookingTime'.
      int bookingTime = service.bookingTime;
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:140:27: Error: The getter 'SliverStaggeredGrid' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'SliverStaggeredGrid'.
                          SliverStaggeredGrid.count(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:247:42: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                  return StaggeredTile.count(4, 4);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:253:42: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                  return StaggeredTile.count(2, 4);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:262:42: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                  return StaggeredTile.count(2, 2);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:265:42: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                  return StaggeredTile.count(4, 2);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:273:42: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                  return StaggeredTile.count(2, 2);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart:275:40: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/home/homepage.dart' ('lib/Screens/home/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
                                return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/Search.dart:179:60: Error: The getter 'REQUEST2' isn't defined for the class 'Screen'.
 - 'Screen' is from 'package:uniyo/class/Util.dart' ('lib/class/Util.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'REQUEST2'.
                  utils.changeScreen(context, utils.screen.REQUEST2);
                                                           ^^^^^^^^
lib/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews4.dart:52:32: Error: The getter 'Lottie' isn't defined for the class 'reviews4'.
 - 'reviews4' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews4.dart' ('lib/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews4.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Lottie'.
                        child: Lottie.asset(
                               ^^^^^^
lib/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews2.dart:26:16: Error: The getter 'Lottie' isn't defined for the class 'reviews2'.
 - 'reviews2' is from 'package:uniyo/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews2.dart' ('lib/Screens/add/supporting_screens_add/reviews2.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Lottie'.
    var anim = Lottie.asset('assets/animations/check9.json',
               ^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Aquick_feedback%2Fquick_feedback.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:623:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:763:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:586:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:85:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
Failed to package /Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/aryuna/studioprojects/Uniyo/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/75/1k4jl9xd4qn5p8fstmtzs43h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Ajgo6z/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirfVfbjn/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Xcode keeps asking me to update to recommended settings 12 repeatedly after updating something is changing them back even tho its specified in podfile swell

Terminal : Encountered error while building for device.

Flutter 2.10.5 • channel stable •
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2